# Server serving double SSL Certs

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I was an idiot 6 months ago and installed some none working SSL cert. 
Now I have manage to find certbot and it had confirmed a sucessfull install. However, i still get served the old cert. 
I don't know how I made that last cert and how to remove it. I have scrambled through my page history without finding the guide I used. I think it might have been done with an application.

Running Nginx

Site: www.charkel.com

What can I do?

Comment: Look at the nginx config files, which are likely in `/etc/nginx`.

Comment: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf say nothing bout cert only this  
# SSL Setting  ##
 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; @ceejayoz

Comment: There's likely a variety of files in that folder. If you're on Ubuntu, there's probably a `sites-available` folder with the per-site configurations. You'll have to look through the files there.

Comment: @ceejayoz 
I have now found the faulty lines in one of the directorys you suggested. But removing the lines or the files gives error. How to get this working with my intsalled certbot

      ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ruweb.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ruweb.key;

Comment: **What** error?

Comment: Removing the lines completly gives a clear error that they are missing and it shuts down. Removing just the keys The site just won't connect. Chrome shows a site is down like page but i think it said the connection refused or endec unexpectedly @ceejayoz